# Create/Run IntelliTests automatically

Tags: intellitest

I have been working with Pex(IntelliTests) for some time now and I wondered if it is possible to create the tests via some sort of command(or .exe) and not through the IDE(VS2015) with right-clicking the function.

I have an automated process which builds my projects and further runs my tests. However if the IntelliTests are not generated anew for the new implementation they are rather useless.

This may seem like a basic question but unfortunately I could not find any information on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command line for IntelliTest is not yet supported. If you would like to see it supported, kindly add your vote here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8623015-enable-intellitest-to-run-in-the-build-pipeline